# cutting off the values at a threshold in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns all of which contain numerical values. The columns represent time steps. I have a threshold which, if reached within the time, stops the values from changing. So let's say the original values are [ 0 , 1.5, 2, 4, 1] arranged in a row, and threshold is 2, then i want the manipulated row values to be [0, 1, 2 , 2, 2]
Is there a way to do this without loops?

A bigger example:

```
>>> threshold = 0.25

>>> input
Out[75]: 
      0    1    2    3    4   
130  0.10 0.20 0.12 0.25 0.20
143  0.11 0.27 0.12 0.28 0.35
146  0.30 0.20 0.12 0.25 0.20
324  0.06 0.20 0.12 0.15 0.20

>>> output
Out[75]: 
      0    1    2    3    4   
130  0.10 0.20 0.12 0.25 0.25
143  0.11 0.27 0.27 0.27 0.27
146  0.30 0.30 0.30 0.30 0.30
324  0.06 0.20 0.12 0.15 0.20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.where(df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)).ffill(axis=1).fillna(df)
print (df)
        0     1     2     3     4
130  0.10  0.20  0.12  0.25  0.25
143  0.11  0.27  0.27  0.27  0.27
146  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30
324  0.06  0.20  0.12  0.15  0.20
```

**Explanation**:

Compare by threshold by `ge` (`>=`):

```
print (df.ge(threshold))
         0      1      2      3      4
130  False  False  False   True  False
143  False   True  False   True   True
146   True  False  False   True  False
324  False  False  False  False  False
```

Create cumulative sum per rows:

```
print (df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1))
     0  1  2  3  4
130  0  0  0  1  1
143  0  1  1  2  3
146  1  1  1  2  2
324  0  0  0  0  0
```

Again for get first matched values:

```
print (df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1))
     0  1  2  3  4
130  0  0  0  1  2
143  0  1  2  4  7
146  1  2  3  5  7
324  0  0  0  0  0
```

Compare by `1`:

```
print (df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1))
         0      1      2      3      4
130  False  False  False   True  False
143  False   True  False  False  False
146   True  False  False  False  False
324  False  False  False  False  False
```

Replace to `NaN`s of no matched values:

```
print (df.where(df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)))
       0     1   2     3   4
130  NaN   NaN NaN  0.25 NaN
143  NaN  0.27 NaN   NaN NaN
146  0.3   NaN NaN   NaN NaN
324  NaN   NaN NaN   NaN NaN
```

Forward fill missing values:

```
print (df.where(df.ge(threshold).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)).ffill(axis=1))

       0     1     2     3     4
130  NaN   NaN   NaN  0.25  0.25
143  NaN  0.27  0.27  0.27  0.27
146  0.3  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30
324  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Replace first values to original:

```
print (df.where(df.ge(threshold).cumsum(1).cumsum(1).eq(1)).ffill(axis=1).fillna(df))
        0     1     2     3     4
130  0.10  0.20  0.12  0.25  0.25
143  0.11  0.27  0.27  0.27  0.27
146  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30
324  0.06  0.20  0.12  0.15  0.20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the steps!

Answer (score 2):

A bit more complicated but I like it.

```
v = df.values
a = v >= threshold

b = np.where(np.logical_or.accumulate(a, axis=1), np.nan, v)

r = np.arange(len(a))
j = a.argmax(axis=1)
b[r, j] = v[r, j]

pd.DataFrame(b, df.index, df.columns).ffill(axis=1)

        0     1     2     3     4
130  0.10  0.20  0.12  0.25  0.25
143  0.11  0.27  0.27  0.27  0.27
146  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30
324  0.06  0.20  0.12  0.15  0.20
```

---

I like this one too:

```
v = df.values
a = v >= threshold
b = np.logical_or.accumulate(a, axis=1)
r = np.arange(len(df))
g = a.argmax(1)
fill = pd.Series(v[r, g], df.index)

df.mask(b, fill, axis=0)

        0     1     2     3     4
130  0.10  0.20  0.12  0.25  0.25
143  0.11  0.27  0.27  0.27  0.27
146  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30  0.30
324  0.06  0.20  0.12  0.15  0.20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I accepted jezrael's because it did appear simpler.

Comment: No worries @dayum.  His answer is great.  I'm just clearing my mind during my own tasks and trying to be helpful while I'm at it (-: